# Grails integration tests and transactions

Tags: grails, transactions, service, integration-testing, spring-transactions

I don't get why this integration test fails. I can get the test to pass by either removing the `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` annotation above the service method, OR by setting `transactional = false` in the Integration Test

I realize that the integration test itself is running in a transaction, and that's why I've got the annotation on the service method.

```
class DbTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

boolean transactional = true
def customerService

void testTransactionsCommit() {
    def orderIds = [1, 2, 3]
    orderIds.each  { // lets make sure they all start out as Active
        def order = Order.get(it)
        order.isActive = true
        order.save(flush:true, validate:true, failOnError: true)
    }

    customerService.cancelOrders(orderIds)

    orderIds.each  {
        def order = Order.get(it).refresh()
        assertEquals false, order.isActive
    }
}
```

and my service method is defined:

```
class CustomerService {

boolean transactional = true
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
def cancelOrders(def orderIds) {
    orderIds.each {
        Order order = Order.get(it)
        if(order.id == 5) //
            throw new RuntimeException('Simulating an exception here, panic!')
        order.isActive = false
        order.save(flush:true, validate:true, failOnError: true)
        println "Order.id = $order.id is ${order.isActive? 'ACTIVE' : 'CANCELLED'}"
    }
}}
```

The Order entity is a simple domain object and I'm on Grails 1.2.1, MySQL 5.x (dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect)

I've seen this related post, but still no cigar :(

[Grails Service Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072648/grails-service-transactions)

Answer (score 8):

*Data changes that a nested, inner, transaction had committed, should be, indeed, instantly visible in the parent transaction.*

And I really don't know why they are *not* in the transactional context of a `GroovyTestCase`. [Others don't know, as well, and are using similar approaches to mine](http://forum.springsource.org/showpost.php?p=284361&postcount=2).

Consider the following test case. The test case, itself, is *not* transactional, but calls a transactional method. - This works as expected.

```
class TransactionalMethodTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    static transactional = false // test case is not transactional
    def customerService

    void testTransactionsCommit() {
        // start a new transaction, 
        // setting order 1 inactive
        setOrderInactive()
        assert ! Order.get(1).isActive
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    private void setOrderInactive() {
        // make sure that order 1 is active
        Order order = Order.get(1)
        order.isActive = true
        order.save(flush:true)

        assert Order.get(1).isActive

        // the following method acts in isolation level
        // Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, which means,
        // a new, nested, transaction is started
        // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        customerService.cancelOrders([1])

        // changes from the nested transaction are
        // visible, instantly
        assert ! Order.get(1).isActive
        // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
}
```

Now consider the following, "normal", transactional, test case. Data changes from within the nested transaction are *not* visible in the parent transaction.

*All I can say is, transactional test cases don't work with nested transactions, so **use the non-transactional test case above**.

If we don't understand the cause, we can, at least, know our options.*

```
class TransactionalTestCaseTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    static transactional = true // default; Propagation.REQUIRED
    def customerService

    void testTransactionsCommit() {
        // make sure that order 1 is active
        Order order = Order.get(1)
        order.isActive = true
        order.save(flush:true)

        assert Order.get(1).isActive

        // the following method acts in isolation level
        // Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, which means,
        // a new, nested, transaction is started
        // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        customerService.cancelOrders([1])

        // the changes from the inner transaction
        // are not yet visible
        assert Order.get(1).isActive
        // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // the changes from the inner transaction
        // are still not visible
        assert Order.get(1).isActive

        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

---

Not related to your primary question, but to your overall intent, here is a test case that checks whether the nested transaction is rolled back, properly:

```
class NestedTransactionRolledBackTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    static transactional = false // test case is not transactional
    def customerService

    void testTransactionsCommit() {
        // start a new transaction, 
        // setting order 1 active
        setOrderActive()
        assert Order.get(1).isActive
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    private void setOrderActive() {
        // make sure that order 1 is active
        Order order = Order.get(1)
        order.isActive = true
        order.save(flush:true)

        assert Order.get(1).isActive

        // the following method acts in isolation level
        // Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, which means,
        // a new, nested, transaction is started.
        // This transaction will fail, and be rolled back.
        // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        shouldFail(NullPointerException) {
            customerService.cancelOrders([1, -999])
        }

        // changes from the nested transaction are
        // visible, instantly.
            // The changes have been rolled back
        assert Order.get(1).isActive
        // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
}
```

---

Finally, some more general sidenotes, it's not `boolean transactional = true` (which appears to work, though), but `static transactional = true`. Your *integration* tests should also `extend` `GroovyTestCase`, not its subclass `GrailsUnitTestCase`, as you don't need the latter's mocking capabilities. The `isActive` field should be named `active` as then, an `isActive()` getter will be automatically generated by naming convention.

Comment: thanks, so it appears that this is a bug with the integration test framework. i.e., the code/logic is correct and works in a running app, but not in the integration test? Perhaps I should JIRA it

Comment: I wouldn't think it's a bug (the issue is too central/prominent) but a design flaw rather. - If you should file a JIRA issue (with the Spring, not Grails, framework), please leave a note at this place.

Comment: A correction to your final example (outdated?): `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` begins a new, _unrelated and independent_ transaction. By contrast, a _nested_ transaction (visible to the parent and with its own save point) occurs under `Propagation.NESTED`. The Spring Javadocs do a great job of explaining the difference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html