# Grails 2.3 IntegrationSpec cannot be transactional false

Tags: grails, spock, transactional, grails-2.3

I upgrade to Grails 2.3 recently and try to migrate all old tests to spock integration test. But it fails at cleanup because my test is non-transactional. The Grails doc says test can be non-transactional, but we need to handle it manually, but it seems not quite right here. as I am getting this error in every integration test extending IntegrationSpec

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot deactivate transaction synchronization - not active
    at grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec.cleanup(IntegrationSpec.groovy:72)
```

A simple test like this would throw that error:

```
import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec

public class DummySpec extends IntegrationSpec {
   static transactional = false

   def setup() {
   }

   def cleanup() {
   }

   def testDummy() {
      expect:
      1 == 1
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this too!  Pretty sure its a grails bug... I submitted a [jira](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10904) and a [patch](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/pull/436).

The error is thrown because the code in grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec does not check for `interceptor.isTransactional()` before calling `interceptor.destroy()`

```
def cleanup() {
  perMethodRequestEnvironmentInterceptor?.destroy()
  perMethodTransactionInterceptor?.destroy()  //breaks :(
}

...

private GrailsTestTransactionInterceptor initTransaction() {
  def interceptor = new GrailsTestTransactionInterceptor(applicationContext)
  if (interceptor.isTransactional(this)) interceptor.init()  //also need for destroy()
  interceptor
}
```

My fix was to add this code:

```
def cleanup() {
  perMethodRequestEnvironmentInterceptor?.destroy()
  destroyTransaction(perMethodTransactionInterceptor)
}

...

private void destroyTransaction(GrailsTestTransactionInterceptor interceptor){
  if (interceptor?.isTransactional(this)) interceptor.destroy()
}
```

To work around for now, you can just create your own com.myname.IntegrationSpec with the patched code and extend that instead of grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec.  Not ideal... but it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Grails 2.3 ships by default with Spock. Just remove your own defined spock dependency make sure to import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec and it should work.